# using javascript during the creation of a view - mvc.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC pattern for .net and I have the following code:

```
<ol class='TextBoxesGroup'>
    @foreach (Employee e in rm.employees)
    {
         <script type="text/javascript">addPrefRow($(this),@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(e.LanId)), @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(e.FirstName+" "+e.LastName)));</script>
    }
</ol>
```

The issue is, in the function "addPrefRow" the first parameter is null. I would like it to be a JQuery Object representing the ordered list.

The function "addPrefRow" creates some html. I would put the html directly in the code above, but there are other times this function is called and I don't want to maintain the html in two places.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Note: if I execute the javascript `alert('test');` it works. So why would I not be able to execute other javascript here?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @{
     // use this var to store the current list id.
     var listId = "";
  }
```

Then give and unique id for each list:

```
 @{
      listId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
  }
```

... and use it to grab the list element:

```
<ol class='TextBoxesGroup' id="@listId">
```

You'll also need to put the call to addPrefRow() inside a jQuery.domready() event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){addPrefRow($("#@listId"), ...;});</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work as I have more than ones of these on the page and this would cause two tags to have the same ID. Sorry, I should have mentioned this.

Comment: @kralco626, I edited the answer. In cases like this you can use a random unique id to identify each element.